# restlet spring jpa

Tags: spring, jpa-2.0, restlet-2.0

There seems to be some known issues with Jersey-Spring-JPA. Does anyone know of any fully implemented simple examples demonstrating Restlet-Spring-JPA? Preferebly using hibernate, glassfish, and mysql.